# How to optimise this Cassandra structure?

Tags: cassandra, cql

So I have this table in Cassandra 3.11

```
CREATE TABLE somekeyspace."Message" (
    id uuid,
    "requestId" text,
    "createdAt" timestamp,
    attachments list<text>,
    body text,
    deleted boolean,
    deleted_by text,
    deleted_on timestamp,
    "extraData" text,
    "isRead" boolean,
    "recipientBrandId" text,
    "recipientId" text,
    "recipientName" text,
    "recipientSpaceId" text,
    "requesterBrandId" text,
    "requesterSpaceId" text,
    "senderId" text,
    "senderName" text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, "requestId", "createdAt")
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("requestId" ASC, "createdAt" DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX "Message_senderId_idx" ON coretail."Message" ("senderId");
CREATE INDEX "Message_requestId_idx" ON coretail."Message" ("requestId");
CREATE INDEX "Message_senderName_idx" ON coretail."Message" ("senderName");
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX fn_prefix ON coretail."Message" (body) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS'};
CREATE INDEX "Message_isRead_idx" ON coretail."Message" ("isRead");
```

Now, I would like to perform one of the following queries:

```
SELECT * from "Message" WHERE ("senderId"=someUserId OR "recipientId"=someUserId) AND body LIKE '%someKeyword';
```

OR:

```
SELECT * from "Message" WHERE "senderId"=someUserId AND body LIKE '%foo';
```

I know these queries are invalid, the question is how to make them work?

- The first one is no good because Cassandra doesn't support OR
- The second is not good because it would require ALLOW FILTERING.

My question: how should I modify the table to be able to select the records whose senderId or recipientId is X and the "body" matches the LIKE query? ALLOW FILTERING is inefficient. How to do this efficiently and preferably with a single query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first thought, is that if you're not going to be querying by `id`, that it should be your last clustering key instead of your partition key.

Comment: Think about using solar search with Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra doesn't natively support the boolean `OR` or `LIKE` operators.

Have a look at the custom indexer called SSTable-Attached Secondary Index (SASI) which supports `PREFIX` and `CONTAIN` operators which are similar to the SQL `LIKE` operator. For example, this query will return a match for Jack or Jill:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE name LIKE 'J%';
```

Note that [SASI is considered experimental](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.10/NEWS.txt#L121-L127) so is not recommended for production use.

There is also [Storage-Attached Indexes](https://www.datastax.com/blog/eliminate-trade-offs-between-database-ease-use-and-massive-scale-sai-storage-attached) (SAI) which is a globally-distributed index available now on [Astra](https://dtsx.io/3oUbsNq), DSE and soon in open-source Apache Cassandra (enhancement proposal [CEP-7](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/7DZ4CQ)).

SAI provides more functionality compared to secondary indexes and is faster at writes with a higher read throughput. For details, see the [SAI docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/using-storage-attached-indexing-sai.html). [Try it for free](https://dtsx.io/3oUbsNq), no credit card required. Cheers!